# excel row to comma separated

Tags: excel, xls, xlsx, vba

I have an xls file with values of the following:

```
ID Value
1 value1
1 value2
1 value3
2 value1
2 value2
3 value1
3 value2
```

etc

I would like to transform this to (create a new sheet)

```
ID Values
1 value1,value2,value3
2 value1,value2
3 value1,value2,value3
```

Basically, I would like all rows that have the same ID to join all values comma separated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub sample()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim temp As String
    Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=Range("C1"), unique:=True

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Row

    j = 1
     For i = 2 To lastRow
        Do Until Cells(j, 2) = ""
            If Trim(Cells(j, 1)) = Trim(Cells(i, 3)) Then
                temp = temp & "," & Cells(j, 2)
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        Cells(i, 4) = temp
        temp = ""
        j = 1
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does the job. I just added temp = Right(temp, Len(temp) - 1) to remove the first comma on line 17.