# Linking cells to comma-separated text

Tags: vba, excel

I have to input a list of names each week into a separate application, which only supports input in a format **"name1", "name2",** ... simply there just always has to be the **name, a comma, space, another name, a comma,**  and so on.

The list of names is usually the same, but their allocation into two groups (present/absent) is always different. So I have to copy (or cut) name by name from the last week's report and paste them name by name into those groups where they belong current week. I was thinking of a macro (ideally button for each name) that would allocate those names in two rows.

[image: my list and desired form]

I would just click various names and it would divide them into those groups. Then I would just copy cells C2 and C4 and paste it in that unfriendly program.

I found something similar here: [excel row to comma separated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598423/excel-row-to-comma-separated)

but I want to distribute those names according to what I have seen at the meeting.

Comment: Do you really need double-quotes around each name as well as commas separating them?

Comment: Hi, I only need those commas and space separating each name, no double quotes. Simply my source is column A, ideally I would have a macro (button) for each name and the results are cells C2 and C4. Cells C1 and C3 are just an example of my groups, just for info.

Answer (score 0):

Use array and join array.

```
Sub mytest()
    Dim vDB, vPresent(), vAbsent()
    Dim n  As Long, i As Long
    vDB = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1) Step 2
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vAbsent(1 To n)
        vAbsent(n) = vDB(i, 1)
        If i + 1 > UBound(vDB, 1) Then Exit For
        ReDim Preserve vPresent(1 To n)
        vPresent(n) = vDB(i + 1, 1)
    Next i
    Range("c2") = Join(vPresent, ", ")
    Range("c4") = Join(vAbsent, ", ")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two buttons, called `Present_button` and `Absent_button`.

The following function reads each cell currently selected and returns a string.

```
Function selected_cells_to_csv() as String
Dim strOutput As String
For Each c In Selection.Cells
    If strOutput <> "" Then strOutput = strOutput & ", "
    strOutput = strOutput & c.Value
Next
selected_cells_to_csv = strOutput
End Function
```

The following two macros are the code behind the respective buttons. Both do the same thing, just putting the returning value into the appropriate cells.

```
Sub Present_Button_Click()
Range("C2").Value = selected_cells_to_csv
End Sub

Sub Absent_Button_Click()
Range("C4").Value = selected_cells_to_csv
End Sub
```

So to use this, highlight all the present people, and click the [Present] button. Then highlight the absent people and click the [Absent] button.

In theory, you could do this all with one button, getting all the selected cells in one pass, then all the unselected cells in the other, but that requires detecting the list etc. and for a once a week process I imagine this is sufficient.